# Histogram buckets show "not defined" while iterating over all metrics in a custom gatherer

Tags: histogram, prometheus, bucket

What should I do to get the length of the buckets array defined for a histogram?
I have defined a histogram metric in prometheus with my custom buckets. But while running a gatherer on all my metrics the Buckets field for the histogram says
`mf.Buckets undefined (type *io_prometheus_client.MetricFamily has no field or method Buckets)`
Need help to access the length of the Buckets field of the histogram through my custom gatherer.

I expected to get the buckets length with *mf.Buckets for the histogram metrics.

Comment: Is this question about using prometheus to expose metrics? And if so, show us your code exposing problematic histogram